# NSMutableURLRequest timeout interval not taken into consideration for POST requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

I have the following problem. On a `NSMutableURLRequest` using the `HTTP` method `POST` the timeout interval set for the connection is ignored. If the internet connection has a problem (wrong proxy, bad dns) the url request fails after about 2-4 minutes but not with   `NSLocalizedDescription = "timed out";`

```
NSUnderlyingError = Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 UserInfo=0x139580 "The request timed out.
```

If the `http` method used is `GET` it works fine. 
   The connection is `async` over `https`.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    

    [request setTimeoutInterval:10];

    //Set the request method to post
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    if (body != nil) {
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
    }

    // Add general parameters to the request
    if (authorization){
        [request addValue: authorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    }
    [request addValue: WS_HOST forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];

    [self addToQueueRequest:request withDelegate:delegate];

'
```

Comment: Try creating the NSMutableURLRequest object with requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: class method?

Answer (score 28):

According to a post on the Apple developer forum, the minimum timeout interval for POST is 240 seconds. Any timeout interval shorter than that is ignored.

If you require a shorter timeout interval, use an async request along with a timer and call cancel on the NSURLConnection as needed.

link to thread: [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/108087#108087%23108087)

Comment: Can someone verify that this is also true for the timeout property when doing a POST with the ASIHTTPRequest framework?

Comment: it's helpful.with default time out I got the error when call to service(in case very bad network) and I set the timeout greater than 240 and it's worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

iOS 6 has fixed this issue.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] 
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20];

[request setHTTPMethod:method];
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
NSLog(@"%f", [request timeoutInterval]); 
//20.0 in iOS 6
//240.0 in iOS 4.3, 5.0, 5.1
```

Answer (score 10):

Fixed with Clay Chambers's suggestion: with a custom timer
Added a timer in a subclass of `NSURLConnection`

```
if (needsSeparateTimeout){

    SEL sel = @selector(customCancel);

    NSMethodSignature* sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:sel];

    NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];

    [invocation setTarget:self];

    [invocation setSelector:sel];

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:WS_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL invocation:invocation repeats:NO];

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

In the custom cancel method the connection is cancelled

```
[super cancel];
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like problem described here is still facing iOS 7.1 (or reappeared). Fortunately it looks like setting [timeoutIntervalForResource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/timeoutIntervalForResource) property on the configuration on the `NSURLSession` can fix this.

**EDIT**

According to @XiOS observations this works for timeouts shorter than (around) 2 minutes.

Comment: Any idea on whether this has any kind of fixes for this in ios8 or still persists in ios8 too?

Comment: Fix is described in my post :)

Comment: Hi Julian Król, That looks good though i havent worked out it yet. My actual issue is when i set a time out interval of 180 seconds for my NSMutableURLRequest, the didFailWithError: delegate gets triggered at the interval ranging from 75 to 220 seconds and some times greater than this , but not exactly at the interval of 180 seconds. I am making asynchronous web service calls with POST method. So do you mean that the specified time out interval will work exactly with NSURLSession?

Comment: I think you should try this out, from my experience on NSMutableURLRequest it didn't work at all whereas for NSURLSession worked fine.

Comment: I tried this out, but the above behaviour i mentioned, remains the same with NSURLSESSION too :(

Comment: Sad, in my case it worked. I have removed timeouts from request and moved them to session and worked like a charm. Which iOS version face a problem in your case?

Comment: i am testing in ios7.1.1 and ios8. What is the interval that you are setting?

Comment: I found that, this is not doing good for greater time out intervals but ofcourse behaving well for time out interval of a minute or two. That was really a right direction towards NSURLSESSION after surfing a lot. Thankyou Julian Król!

Comment: Thanks for the update I will update my answer according to your observation :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to handle timeout error , I think no one answer this question yet

Let me write pice of my code to Explain that point

```
// replace "arg" with your argument you want send to your site 
 NSString * param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arg"];

    NSData *Postdata = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[Postdata length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
// replace "yoursite" with url of site you want post to 
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http//yoursite"]]];
// set what ever time you want in seconds 120 mean 2 min , 240 mean 4 min 
    [request setTimeoutInterval:120];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:Postdata];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

// if request time out without response from server error will occurred 

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection * ) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {    
    if (error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) 
        // handle error as you want 
        NSLog(@"Request time out , Please try again later");
}
```

I hope this help with any one ask how to handle timeout error