# iPhone SDK: URL request not timing out

Tags: iphone, timeout, nsurlconnection

I am having a problem with a network request that should timeout, but the method is not called. The request is as follows:

```
#define kCONNECT_TIMEOUT 20.0

request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: aUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
postData = [jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
[request setTimeoutInterval:kCONNECT_TIMEOUT];
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
assert(self.connection != nil);
```

This should get a callback to

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)_error
```

But after 4 minutes no error message is displayed. Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466389/nsmutableurlrequest-timeout-interval-not-taken-into-consideration-for-post-reques

Comment: This issue is fixed in ios 4 onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A representative from Apple has divulged that SDK 3.0 and later enforce a minimum timeout of (you guessed it) four minutes:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/25282

If you try to set a timeout value of less than 240 seconds, it gets clamped up to 240.  If you need a shorter timeout, I cast my vote for St3fan's solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want better timeout management on http requests using `NSURLConnection` then it is much better to run the request *asynchronous* together with an `NSTimer` that can cancel the `NSURLConnection` when it fires because the timeout period expired.

This also means you don't have to deal with threads, which is generally a good idea. Async event (runloop) based operations are the way to go in 99.9% of the cases on the iPhone.

Comment: I thought the above code was asynchronous, is it not? So what you are saying is that request setTimeoutInterval is broken and better to explicitly define a separate timer instead?

Comment: Sorry you are right. Your code is async. But yes, the same applies .. if you want better control over the timeout then simply run a timer next to the request.

Comment: I recently did a demo app and there was no internet connection and I noticed that yes it did time out as it should. This is using iOS 4, so perhaps this issue is fixed now.