# timeout value for ios facebook sdk request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios4

hey guys does the ios facebook sdk asynchronous request delegate allow developer to specify some sort of timeoutInterval value?  i know that the nsURLRequest has a timeoutInterval value that u can set.

Thanks for your help.

scenario:
i make an async request call.  the connection dies after the request call goes out and before the response comes back.  currently, i have no way of detecting this. what i want is: i call line number 2.  after 10 sec, no response comes back, line 5 would get execute.  Or something along the line that there were an error.

```
    1 - // async request call
    2 - [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" addParams:nil andDelegate:self];

    3 - // delegate
    4 - - (void) request :(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {}
    5 - - (void) request :(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError :(NSError *)error {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see Facebook ios SDK, FBRequest.m file at the beginning:

```
static const NSTimeInterval kTimeoutInterval = 180.0;
```

then it is used by a connect method. You can change it or patch the SDK so it could be set externally.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

FBRequest.m applies it's timeoutInterval to NSMutableURLRequest, which ignores/overrides anything under 240 seconds. If your interested, read more about that here...

[iPhone SDK: URL request not timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471475/iphone-sdk-url-request-not-timing-out)

...otherwise it basically means the kTimeoutInterval in FBRequest.m is ignored if set to < 240, so don't bother with it.

I've just gone through this issue myself, I ended up using an NSTimer that will cancel the pending FBRequest's connection on timeout. see details here..

[Facebook API - How to cancel Graph Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958912/facebook-api-how-to-cancel-graph-request/8265414#8265414)