# How to test the timeout on posting the NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: iphone, ios

I encounter a problem from our QA team, our QA team want to test the our app can manage rightly when time out happend sending the NSMutableURLRequest, according to a post on the Apple developer forum, the minimum timeout interval for POST is 240s [NSMutableURLRequest timeout interval not taken into consideration for POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466389/nsmutableurlrequest-timeout-interval-not-taken-into-consideration-for-post-reque)

But how can I make this request timeout, even don't change the server code.

Comment: Set urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 0.05; , check whether didFailWithError method is fired or not

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, I'm so foolish, it works on the iOS6.

Comment: But why sometimes it's also not working on iOS6, set the timeoutINterval.