# iOS Gmail API: Timeout interval and RPC vs RESTful implementation

Tags: ios, gmail-api, google-api-objc-client

The Gmail iOS API under the hood appears to be creating 'POST' requested with a payload that specifies an action. So for example if I want to get a single message by ID, I would expect (at least since the documentation on the API specifies it) that I would create a GET request with the correct URL schema. Instead the Gmail iOS implementation does not and utilizes more of an RPC approach. Unfortunately this means all POST requests have a default timeout of 240 seconds and cannot be changed, apparently an iOS bug/weird implementation. I can create a timer and cancel the request but why not make the implementation RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a quark with the Google iOS client libraries in general--they do not follow the standard REST semantics of the APIs like all the other client libraries use.  I imagine due to some limitation in iOS.  In any case, https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ would be the best place to read more about it, discuss and file bugs.  (Not specific to the gmail-api.)

Answer (score 0):

The library was written to create JSON-RPC requests because those have always supported a batch request model. A mechanism for batch REST requests was added much later to Google's JSON API servers.

The timeout issue on POSTs was resolved in iOS 6, according to discussions online like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901133).

The [project site](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) does have links to the library's discussion group and issue tracker.